# Why my android application stopped when I run it in Emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation, manifest

> Unfortunately, *app* has stopped.

I get this error when I'm running my application in the emulator. Why?
My program doesn't contain any error, but it's not running.

I use Eclipse with SDK.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jvstgs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Tetris"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my LogCat

> 06-09 07:30:20.989: D/AndroidRuntime(627): Shutting down VM
>   06-09 07:30:20.989: W/dalvikvm(627): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a122a0)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.jvstgs/com.example.jvstgs.Tetris}: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10044 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10044 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:288)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:309)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:288)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at com.example.framework.impl.GLGame.onResume(GLGame.java:66)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
>   06-09 07:30:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(627):    ... 12 more

Comment: Wow, everyone's quick on the trigger today! ;) So, like everyone's saying...it's failing on your wake_lock permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with your permissions:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10044 nor current process
>   has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Update your manifest to include this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

**Your Stack Trace**

Btw, the reason everyone is able figure out your problem so quickly, is because your logcat clearly shows what your error is.

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) to learn more about how to read a stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

If you read your logs, you'll see this:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10044 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

Which means you need to add android.permission.WAKE_LOCK to your AndroidManifest.xml

Please read this: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

> To use a wake lock, the first step is to add the WAKE_LOCK permission
>   to your application's manifest file:

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `WAKE_LOCK_PERMISSION` to your manifest `uses-permission`.

More info here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK